# How can I resize a UITableViewCell and center it onscreen smoothly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to grow a selected cell to almost fill the screen.

I am familiar with changing the height of the cell using `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`, but the result is a cell the correct size which is partly offscreen.

I can scroll so the cell is centred onscreen, with `setContentOffset:` or `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:`, but this is a separate animation from the height change, which doesn't look good.

Is there a way to combine the two and smoothly grow a cell so it is centred and bigger?

Comment: Could you add both the code to update the height and the code to center the cell to your post.

Comment: I don't think that would help anyone answer the question.  It would be 3 lines of codes, using the methods already mentioned in the question, and passing barely any parameters.

Comment: But the place where you put the code is important I think, but whatever you think is right..

Comment: Have you thought of trying KVO to observe changes to some property (such as the cell size) and then using that observation to change the table offset? Not looked into the details, but worth a thought.

Comment: I could experiment with that.  The danger is that changing the table offset will set one of the properties being animated and kill the animation.  Will try and report back.